# Instantly using auto-increment value in insert

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

This is a question nagging me a long time now. Suppose I have a table with two columns (`id` and `file`). Is there a way to use the auto-incremented id instantly in the insert query? Like this:

```
INSERT INTO `sometable` (`file`) VALUES (CONCAT(id, '-somename.ext'));
```

But this results in `file` being "0-somename.ext".

Of course I could just do an update right after the insert and use the id there. But I just wonder if there is any way to do it in just one swift insert.

### Update

I am searching for a solution that works even if the table is empty or no other insert has been made before. `LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1` does not work, because it returns 0 if used on the first insert (even if the table is not empty). If the insert before was made to another table, it returns a wrong id altogether.

Why is there no standard solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test (id int AUTO_INCREMENT, tx text, PRIMARY KEY (id));

insert into test(tx) values ('first');

insert into test(tx) values(concat( LAST_INSERT_ID() +1, 'blabla'));

insert into test(tx) values(concat( LAST_INSERT_ID() +1, 'blabla'));

insert into test(tx) values(concat( LAST_INSERT_ID() +1, 'blabla'));
```